# Can not change the color of the font intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Im trying to change the color of the font in IntelliJ but I can't seem to find how go into setting -> appearance -> theme and it changes the look of IntelliJ and some of the font changes like the color of text Strings and keywords like import but not the color of methods and variables a more

They just stay all the same color until is somehow use it for example if I declare the variable B like this

`int B;`

The color does not change.

But if I do

`int B = 1;` it does change to the color is supposed to be

See the picture I added:

[image]

I also tried settings -> editor -> color scheme

Answer (score 1):

Use color settings under the Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | **Color Scheme**. For example,  Color Scheme | Java | Methods | **Method call**.

See [Configuring colors and fonts﻿](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-colors-and-fonts.html).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot color individual methods and variables in Intellij.

Comment: i just want them to be for example all methods to be green color and all variables  red not individual  check the pic i linked to see my problem